# How to run Clojure-tests in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, clojure

I'd like to execute my Clojure tests directly from eclipse (alternative would be to run `lein test` from the commandline).

I already installed the CounterClockwise-Plugin for Eclipse, but there is no "Run as / Clojure test" in the context-menu. So far I added a `(run-tests)` to the end of my Clojure-tests files and execute the test via "Run as / Clojure Application".

Is there a better way to run tests from eclipse? In general it shouldn’t be necessary to add code to start the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a project REPL in Eclipse, move the REPL to the test namespace and `(run-tests)` from there.